# Expo managed workflow - Gradle error : Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

After removing a dependency from my expo managed workflow project, Gradle start crashing with this error upon building with EAS. On iOS it's still building just fine.

The dependency that I removed

```
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.19.0",
```

And the error that happen next

```
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules jetified-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1)
```

I'm using expo 47, and nothing funny seems configured in the `android` keys of app.json & eas.json files.

Adding back `@stripe/stripe-react-native` library, make the build work just fine. But I want to remove this dependency !

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to remove the `"@stripe/stripe-react-native"` dependency without error after upgrading to expo 50